# Apache virutalhost subdomains point to same directory

Tags: apache, ubuntu, virtualhost

elloo,

i have two virtualhost subdomains point to different directories however when i load both subdomains in the browser, i get them both pointing to same directory. here is my vhost.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
        ServerName subdomain1.domain.com 
        ServerAlias *.domain.com

        #Indexes + Directory Root.
        DirectoryIndex index.php        
        DocumentRoot /subomain1/path/to/directory/trunk

        #Logfiles
        ErrorLog  /subomain1/path/to/directory/trunk/error.log
        CustomLog /subomain1/path/to/directory/trunk//access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
        ServerName subdomain1.domain.com 
        ServerAlias *.subdomain.com

        DirectoryIndex index.php        
        DocumentRoot /subomain1/path/to/directory/trunk

        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile /ssl/certs/subdomain1.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /ssl/private/subdomain1.key
        SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown
 </VirtualHost>

 <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
        ServerName subdomain2.domain.com 
        ServerAlias *.domain.com

        #Indexes + Directory Root.
        DirectoryIndex index.php        
        DocumentRoot /subomain2/path/to/directory/trunk

        #Logfiles
        ErrorLog  /subomain2/path/to/directory/trunk/error.log
        CustomLog /subomain2/path/to/directory/trunk//access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
        ServerName subdomain2.domain.com 
        ServerAlias *.subdomain.com

        DirectoryIndex index.php        
        DocumentRoot /subomain2/path/to/directory/trunk

        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile /ssl/certs/subdomain2.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /ssl/private/subdomain2.key
        SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown
 </VirtualHost>
```

i have  tried google however none of the answers seems to help.

i'm using ubuntu server

many thanks in advance

Comment: Never seen a serveralias *.mydomain.tld ... did you try without this line?

Answer (score 1):

don't know if you ever solved this, but i was having the same problem and it turned out i forgot to change the httpd.conf file like this:

> Open the “httpd.conf” and uncomment line #461 (approx) which reads “Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf”, then save.

taken from this tutorial which is priceless:
http://kevchapman.co.uk/development/setting-up-apache-on-snow-leopard/

Answer (score 0):

I think its because youre using 
ServerAlias *.domain.com
on both virtual hosts

since the ServerAlias directive indicates that the listed names are other names which people can use to see that same web site:

ServerAlias *.subdomain.com

then requests for all hosts in the subdomain.com domain will be served by the subdomain1.domain.com virtual host.

this might help http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/name-based.html